# Calculating custom coordinates

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have a set of four coordinates with which I am creating a rectangular path in svg as following. This rectangular path has width of 10 and height of 150.

```
|     point#       |          x    |          y    |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|
| 0                | 650           | 300           |
| 1                | 650           | 150           |
| 2                | 640           | 150           |
| 3                | 640           | 300           |
```

[image]

I need to apply rotation (r) to this path on coordinate 650,300. Let's suppose r=85deg and below is what hapens to the path after rotation.

[image]

After the transformation, I need to ensure that the opposite arm of the rectangle still stays on the green line. How can I calculate the new coordinate where it would extend to the base green like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is a representation using [geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/)

[image: Schema]

The rectangle ABCD is your original rectangle (I have used up increasing coordinates under geogebra), A'B'C'D' is the same rectangle after applying a 85° rotation at point (650,300). If I have correctly understood your question, you want to know the coordinates of the point noted I on the graphic.

We know $\angle{A'I, A'D}' = r$. We know $\angle{D'A', D'I}$ is a right angle. And as $A'D'$ is obtained from $AD$ by a rotation, both segments have same length: $10$ units.

We can immediately conclude $A'D' = A'I cos(r)$ or $A'I = \dfrac {A'D'}{cos(r)}$.

Numeric application: $A'I = \dfrac{10}{cos(85)}\approx 114.74$.

So $I$ is the point of coordinates $(535.26, 300)$

Comment: @smpa01: It should. I have just tested it and it worked fine. Could a firewall be on the way?

Comment: @smpa01: from the landing page, the *Start Calculator* button opens the GeoGebra calculator...

Comment: Geogebra is rather easy to use... Unfortunately, I have not saved anything. Anyway, since I have discovered it, I really think that it is a must have as soon as you want to do geometry with 2D coordinates. I advise you to play a little with it, just try to reproduce the schema I have built. Hint: first use *Tools* to create 4 points and use them to build the rectangle and the base line, then use *Algebra* to provide the expected coordinates. From that point dezoom and pan to see the figure. Use rotation from the *Tools* tab to build the rotated rectangle and the construction line...

Comment: ... Then *Intersection* (still from *Tools* tab) will create the intersection point, and you will be able to directly read its coordinates in the *Algebra* tab. Good luck...